# Jive - Get current blog post from app

Tags: opensocial, jive

I'm developing an **app** which has a `Content Action` and an `!app Action`.

I would like to get via **javascript** (i.e. Open Social API I suposse...) the current user (I got it!) and the current blog post (blogpost id) from both actions.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

You can do it adding an `gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler()` listener, and inside it you should call the `osapi.jive.core.container.getLaunchContext(function (selection) {})`;

From **selection** object you can get the type and the id:

```
var type = selection.jive.content.type;  
var contentid = selection.jive.content.id
```

You have a full example from [Jive Developers Website](https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-126665)